# Private folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to create a private folder in my codeigniter website, and I want to be able to access it in my code in order to upload or write files, but I don't want this folder to be visible or accessed by other visitors.

Comment: Err, place the folder outside the webroot?

Comment: Thz .htaccess file worked as suggested by @zayn ali

Comment: I'm glad it helped @EssaidiM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this file in your folder you want to be private

.htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```